# Dynamic URL routing is not working in django web application

Tags: html, css, django

A am working on a simple application, where trying to generate Dynamic URl and routing take place as per the ID in the url.
Dynamic value is getting populated in the URL, but it not performing action that needed.

prop_listings.html HTML Page:-

```
 <div class="row text-secondary pb-2">
   <div class="col-6">
    <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ listing.list_date | timesince }}
   </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <a href="{% url 'morelisting' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

URL.py in App Listings:-

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.PropListings,name="prop_listings"),
    path('<int:listing_id>', views.mlisting, name="morelisting"),

]
```

Views.py :-

```
def mlisting(request, listing_id):
#  listingDetl = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)
  listingDetl = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
  print(listingDetl.username, listingDetl.address,listingDetl.city)

  context = {
    'listingDetails': listingDetl
  }

  return render(request,'listings/detail_listing.html', context)
```

URL.py in MainProject:-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('static_pages.urls')),
    path('user_account/', include('user_account.urls')),
    path('listings/', include('listings.urls')),
    path('feedback/', include('feedback.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Am trying to redirect the page from prop_listings.html to detail_listing.html, based on the below tag URL generated on listing.id

```
<a href="{% url 'morelisting' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>
```

It's not working as expected on-click of above tag.
But when i did inspect on the same, URL is getting generated properly and when i click on the url, it will work as expected.

[Inspect on the html page, URL populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXIro.png)

I looked into similar issue threads and tried to make changes, but not able to fix it.
Not getting what the issue and how to correct it.

Comment: You can get url in backend as well as in front end from ```request.path``` object. If i am understanding you incorrectly so please comment.

Comment: Append slash to the URL  - path('<int:listing_id>/', views.mlisting, name="morelisting"). If view function is not called then there is problem with communication between URL and views, first area of troubleshooting is to be looking into URL mapping (urls.py) file. If it doesn't work , please comment

Comment: @shahsawood, yes am getting listing.id from backend and building the URL path. I need to display the records individually based on the ID

Comment: @B.Anup, i tried appending the slash as well. but no changes. URL is building.  Below is url generated for different listing.id <a href="/listings/3/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>

Comment: @B.Anup, i tried appending the slash as well. but no changes. URL is building.  Below is url generated for different listing.id when  checked using inspect.                                                                              
  <a href="/listings/3/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>                  
  <a href="/listings/2/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>          Clicking on the href url, View function is called and detail_listing.html get loaded. but same is not happening when click on "More Info" in prop_listings.html,  view function is not called.

Comment: As per my understanding, view function is called if you type the "/listings/2" url in the browser but view function is not called on clicking "More Info". If I am correct, Are you getting any log/error message in your developer tools console or in backend interpreter?

Comment: @B.Anup, if i type the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/2/" it will call view function and i just tried accessing  "/listings/2"  from the inspect panel, it will work similar to above url.  But not called on clicking "More Info". Am not getting any error message, i don't have any logs as well.

Comment: @Rajesh ```<a>``` don't work like in normal html where you can redirect from one page to another. In django you will create views for different actions. I see your ```mlisting``` which is okay and will render ```detail_listing.html``` by click on the button in ```prop_listings.html```.

Comment: @shahsawood, i agree with how <a> work in normal html and django. problem is detail_listing.html is not rendering on click of button in prop_listings.html.

Comment: Just found that functionality is working with Bootstrap 4 CSS not with Bootstrap 5 CSS, any suggestions to fix the same with Bootstrap 5

Comment: Card deck is not supported by bootstrap 5, that the issue.